# Why does the lock screen change monitor resolution?

Tags: release-freya

Whenever I lock my PC the monitors change resolution (or something) making the whole locking/unlocking process slower.

Comment: OP, please edit your question to only contain one question. Separate questions must be asked separately.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/pantheon-greeter-login-screen-has-incorrect-resolution-on-external-monitor) to potentially help you with your resolution issue.

I would assume the audio switching off is by design. Personally, I appreciate that feature.