# Multiple display resolution issue on lock screen

Tags: greeter, resolution

So i just downloaded the Loki 0.4.1.

The issue is that when I lock the screen with an external monitor connected to my laptop (it has a different resolution), the lock screen tries to change resolution multiple times during its black screen process which results in slower locking and if I have sound going through eg spotify the sound freezes multiple times, althoguh it continues afterwards

Is there a way i can disable the resolution change on lock?

Also note that I have installed the latest nvidia driver (390)

Answer (score 1):

Go here, it fixed the issue for me. Ensure you note carefully the outputs when you `grep` using `xrandr`. They are key to the bash script.

[Pantheon-greeter login screen has incorrect resolution on external monitor](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/pantheon-greeter-login-screen-has-incorrect-resolution-on-external-monitor)

My code example:

```
#!/bin/bash

Samsung="$(xrandr -q | grep 'HDMI-1 connected' | awk '{ print $1 }')"
if [ "$Samsung" = "HDMI-1" ]; then
  xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
  xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080
fi
```