# Login screen incorrect resolution

Tags: release-juno, resolution

I have noticed that everytime I lock desktop resolution of lock screen change to I guess 800 something while my resolution of desktop is 1920x900.

Comment: Please add more information of your system (such as video driver information) so it helps people better understand the scenario. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here
I've got 2 monitors (Samsung, 2048x1152, primary; LG, 1680x1050). 
After (re)boot: the resolution on the primary screen is correct.
After login: on lock screen, the resolution changes to 1280x1024.

here my xrandr-infos from lock screen:

```
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024     77.00*
```

After unlock screen the resolution changes back to the correct values. But sometimes my desktop is pixelated.

I already tried to create a script like here: 
[Pantheon-greeter login screen has incorrect resolution on external monitor](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/pantheon-greeter-login-screen-has-incorrect-resolution-on-external-monitor)

But it does'nt work.

Any other ideas?

---

Update: 
I've got this issue after install nvidia driver 340.108